# Having trouble with converting a decimal number to a binary

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, binary, decimal

I'm making a program that converts a string that the user enters such as "APPLE" into a binary number through the corresponding ASCII numbers that represent each character of the string "APPLE." For example A = 65 in ascii etc.. I've created a function that converts the string into a binary but it doesn't seem to be working. It displays "The equivalent binary number is: 0031F240for A" in an infinite loop and gives me "0031F240for" instead of being in the binary version of 65. I know this function works for converting a decimal number into binary because I've tried it, but I think my implementation of the bin[] array is messing things up. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class RandomString
{
    private:
        string input;
        string bin[100];

    public:

RandomString() : bin(), input("")
{

}

void getData()
{
    cout << "Enter the word to be encoded into a binary file.";
    cin >> input;
}

void numToBin()
{
    int i = 0;
    int len = input.length();
    int num = int(input[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        while(num != 0)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
                bin[i].insert(0, "0");
            else
                bin[i].insert(0, "1");

            num = num / 2;
            cout << "The equivalent binary number is: " << bin << "for " << input[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
void display()
{
}


};
```

Comment: I think we need to do ` num = num / 2;` in both cases. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be in both cases and that was my mistake. However, it still ends up spitting out the same thing as the output.

Comment: what is type of bin, i don't understand. if you use `string` then use a `string str="";` and for condition `str=str+(num%2==0?"0":"1");`

Comment: I have to use an array for my bin which is of type string because if the user enters another word of different length such as pineapple then I need it to convert all of the characters of pineapple into binary. I have edited my post to include all of my code.

Comment: You can refer this :http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/cpp/binary.html

Comment: The reference is basically the same as my function for converting a decimal number to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test if the result is correct but this code convert a string to binary. Probably you have to modify it to fit with ASCII codes.

```
void DecimalToBinary(char a,std::vector<char>& v)
{
  if(a==0)
      v.push_back(0);
  if(a==1)
      v.push_back(1);
  else
    {
      v.push_back(a%2);
      DecimalToBinary(a/2,v);
    }
}



int main()
{
  std::vector<char> v;
  std::string line;
  getline(std::cin,line);
  std::istringstream input(line);
  char c;
  while(input >> c)
    {
  DecimalToBinary(c,v);
    }

  std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,""));  
}
```

First Your while loop never stops because you don't change the value of `i` inside the while loop, so `int(input[i])` has always the same value, you have to use `break` somewhere or `i++`, but I don't know if the result is correct,I think recursion is better than while in this situation, but anyway try the following:

```
   void numToBin()
{
    int i = 0;
    int len = input.length();
    int num = int(input[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        while(int(input[i]) != 0)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
          {
                bin[i].insert(0, "0");
        break;
          }
            else
            {
                bin[i].insert(0, "1");
                num = num / 2;
            }
            cout << "The equivalent binary number is: " << bin << "for " << input[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Second, doing `std::cout << bin` you print a memory address, not the contents of the bin.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting your code, but I have on idea how to use vector and what not... I would appreciate it if you can help me point out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @user2419691 what type is the input, string? can you post all of your code?

Comment: yes, it is a type string. I have edited my original post to include all of my code.

Comment: your while never stops, you have to use break but anyway I don't think the result of your function is correct. Also doing `std::cout << bin` you print a memory address, not the contents of the array @user2419691

Comment: Okay, I fixed my `cout << bin[i]` and why do I need to use break if the condition of my while loop should stop it once it is done with the conversion from ASCII to binary?

Comment: @user2419691 you don't change the i inside the while brackets, so the `int(input[i])` has always the same value and the loop never stops

Comment: I've tried your method of break and it doesn't print out the binary. It prints out 0 and then moves on to the next character and does the same. I've reworked my function to print out the binary for A but it won't print out the binary for the rest of the word. It ends up printing out "The equivalent binary number is: P" etc. all the way to the last character of the string."The equivalent binary number is: E"

Comment: It's better to use recursion, I am pretty sure that the problem can also be solved using while loops but the code is more complex and not readable. Modify your function to call itself. Check mine `DecimalToBinary`. I can't help more :)

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what the error was and now the function works perfectly fine. Thank you for your help. It ended up being that I had to put `int num = int(input[i]);` inside the for loop instead of outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(int(input[i]) != 0)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
                bin[i].insert(0, "0");
            else
            {
                bin[i].insert(0, "1");

            }
            num = num / 2;// this line should be in both case.
            cout << "The equivalent binary number is: " << bin << "for " << input[i] << endl;
        }
```

I've changed `num = num / 2` for both cases. Please check it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be in both cases and that was my mistake. However, it still ends up spitting out the same thing as the output.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the 'bin' in

> cout << "The equivalent binary number is: " << bin

to 'bin[i]'.

Because 'bin' is a string array, also the pointer/address to the string array, so 'cout << bin' will always output the address.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I saw my error after someone pointed out and did that immediately. I've got my code to print out the binary for A but it won't print out the binary for the rest of the word. It ends up printing out "The equivalent binary number is: P" etc. all the way to the last character of the string.